# How can I apply setActive to a UI element after an animation finishes?

Tags: unity, c#, animation, gui

I have an object animation which plays on the opening of a scene. When the animation is over I want the UI slider to be setActive - allowing the user to rotate the object. I have both these elements in place and working individually - just can't quite work out how to go about combining them.

Any help or advice about what approach I should take is much appreciated.

The animation was created in Maya.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by waiting until the animation ends. You can use IEnumarator to do it if your function is not in the Update loop.

```
public Animator anim;
public Slider slider;


public void WaitAnimaitonEnds()
{
    StartCoroutine(WaitTillAnimEnds());
}

IEnumerator WaitTillAnimEnds()
{

    yield return new WaitForSeconds((anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length + anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime));
    // do whatever you want
    slider.SetActive(true);
    // do whatever you want
}
```

If you are looking for the alternative ways to do it, you can check the documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimatorStateInfo.html).

Answer (score 1):

From [Unity Answers](https://answers.unity.com/comments/1208738/view.html):

> I find it easier to just add AnimationEvents to the clip at the start and/or end which, in your case, stop and start the movement by calling those functions. It's much more reliable than using a CoRoutine because an AnimationState might get interrupted and this wouldn't be caught be the CR timer.

From [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43873558/6301627):

> You can use events on animation clips. It's explained in Unity manual:
> https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationEventsOnImportedClips.html
>
> In **Animation Inport Settings** in **Annimations** tab You can find **Event** heading. Position the playback to the end and click **Add Event**. Fill the **Function** field with name of the function to call at the end of animation. Just make sure that Game Object with this animation has a corresponding function.

---

Another approach, from [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1344666/view.html):

> This is super old thread, but as far as i can see, "Add Behaviour" in Animator can solve this problem. That will create the script for your state, which has several methods handy for such requirements.
>
> Check this out: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/StateMachineBehaviour.html
>
> Cheers